# How to navigate back in nested graph from the third level to the second level?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I have a `Single Activity` project with `Navigation Drawer`. And I realized the navigation possibility by `Navigation Components`. I created a `nav_graph.xml` that can route and open each `Fragment` from the `Navigation Drawer`. And it is enough for one level routing. But my project has two and sometimes three-level routing. So I created a nested navigation graph for that `nav_nested_settings`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/nav_fragment_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_fragment_home"
        android:name="com.app.ui.fragment.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/nav_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">
        // other actions ...
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_fragment_home_to_nav_fragment_fragment"
            app:destination="@id/nav_nested_settings" />
    </fragment>
    // ... other fragments
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_fragment_search"
        android:name="com.app.ui.fragment.search.SearchFragment"
        android:label="@string/nav_search"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_search" />
    <include app:graph="@navigation/nav_settings" />
</navigation>
```

and the nested graph is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tool="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_nested_settings"
    android:label="@string/nav_settings"
    app:startDestination="@id/nav_fragment_settings">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_fragment_settings"
        android:name="com.app.ui.fragment.settings.main.SettingsFragment"
        android:label="@string/nav_settings"
        tool:layout="@layout/fragment_settings">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_fragment_settings_to_nav_fragment_settings_ads"
            app:destination="@id/nav_fragment_settings_ads" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_fragment_settings_to_nav_fragment_settings_app"
            app:destination="@id/nav_fragment_settings_app" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_fragment_settings_to_nav_fragment_settings_home"
            app:destination="@id/nav_fragment_settings_home" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_fragment_settings_ads"
        android:name="com.app.ui.fragment.settings.ads.SettingsAdsFragment"
        android:label="@string/nav_settings_ads"
        tool:layout="@layout/fragment_settings_ads" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_fragment_settings_app"
        android:name="com.app.ui.fragment.settings.app.SettingsAppFragment"
        android:label="@string/nav_settings_app"
        tool:layout="@layout/fragment_settings_app" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_fragment_settings_home"
        android:name="com.app.ui.fragment.settings.home.SettingsHomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/nav_settings_home"
        tool:layout="@layout/fragment_settings_home">
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

If I choose `Settings` from `Navigation Drawer` the app opens it. And then I click on `ads` / `app` / `home` button and the opens the next `Fragment`. But If I click `back` button or arrow in the app toolbar - nothing is happening.

How to solve that issue? How to navigate back in nested graph from the third level to the second level?

**upd 01**
// added function that sets up the NavController and AppBarConfiguration

```kotlin
private fun initNavigation() {
        mNavController = findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment)
        navView.setupWithNavController(mNavController)
        mAppBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(mNavController.graph, drawerLayout)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(mNavController, mAppBarConfiguration)
}
```

**upd02**
I have found one helpful thing/bug. The back button is working fine without any additional code. But when I click on the back button the app repeats the previous action "go from SettingsFragment to SettingsAdsFragment", for example.
I use moxy lib with default strategy - `AddToEndSingleStrategy`.

Comment: Check that your `Single Activity` has `onSupportNavigateUp()` overriden, that's the only thing that comes up to my mind from what you shared. `override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean = navController.navigateUp()`

Comment: @DatPhamTat, yes. ```override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean { return mNavController.navigateUp(mAppBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp() }``` And I can go back from Navigation Drawer Fragments  (level one)

Comment: It seems like your problem is in your **upd02** comment, but you haven't included any of that code.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Because I didn't think that it can break the app flow. Usually, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, I think your `onSupportNavigateUp()` is not entirely correct. I have implemented several apps with navDrawer and navigation, and the way I override `onSupportNavigateUp()` is as follow:

```
// the activity hosting your navigation
class HostActivity : AppCompatActivity {
    // flag if for the currently shown fragment, navigating up is enabled
    // should be false for top level fragments, i.e. those accessible from navDrawer
    // should be set to true for lower level fragments
    private var canNavigateUp: Boolean = false
    
    ...

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return if (canNavigateUp) {
            mNavController.navigateUp()
        } else {
            NavigationUI.navigateUp(mNavController, mAppBarConfiguration)
        }
    }

    fun setNavigation(navigateUpEnabled: Boolean) {
        supportActionBar?.let { actionBar ->
            canNavigateUp = navigateUpEnabled
            if (navigateUpEnabled) {
                // set up icon
                actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(null)
                lockUnlockDrawer(lock = true)
            } else {
                // set drawer icon
                actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
                lockUnlockDrawer(lock = false)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, for top level fragments, i.e. those acessible directly from the navDrawer:

```
class TopLevelFragment : Fragment() {
    ...
    
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        (activity as? HostActivity)?.setNavigation(false)
    }
}
```

And for lower level fragments (ads/app/home):

```
class LowLevelFragment : Fragment() {
    ...
    
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        (activity as? HostActivity)?.setNavigation(true)
    }
}
```

This should work, assuming you have your `mNavController` and `mAppBarConfiguration` correctly set up.

Comment: I have copied all code from your answer but it doesn't help me.  You mentioned that I should correctly set up my NavController and AppBarConfiguration. I have just updated my question and added a function that sets up them. Could you please check it?

Comment: I made a working demo that reflects your case, you can find it here:
https://github.com/phamtdat/NavigationDemo

Check it out and try to compare it with your code.

Comment: Thank you! I have just checked it and my code is the same. And I think that the root of the issue is hidden in Moxy lib strategy

Comment: You should not be messing with `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled` when you are using `setupActionBarWithNavController()` - it is already doing the right thing for you based on the top level destinations you've set on your `AppBarConfiguration`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution!

I should use the correct strategy for the Moxy library. Yes, I didn't say anything about that lib in the topic because I didn't think that it can break the app flow.

Old Strategy type for interface methods

```
StateStrategyType(AddToEndSingleStrategy::class)
interface SettingsView : BaseMvpView {
    fun showManageAdsFragment()
    fun showManageAppUIFragment()
    fun showManageHomeUIFragment()
}
```

New Strategy type for interface methods

```
StateStrategyType(SkipStrategy::class)
interface SettingsView : BaseMvpView {
    fun showManageAdsFragment()
    fun showManageAppUIFragment()
    fun showManageHomeUIFragment()
}
```